# Mutate error when attempting to recode - object not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I’m trying to change the Gender variable in my dataset to a character variable (i.e., 1 = male, 2 = female, 3 = other)

The code I attempted to run is the following

```
bwdata6 <- bwdata6 %>% mutate(across(c(Gender),
~recode(.x, ‘1’ = male, ‘2’ = female, ‘3’ = other)))
```

The error message I got is below.

```
Error: Problem with mutate() input ..1.
x object ‘male’ not found
i Input ..1 is across(c(Gender), ~recode(.x, 1= male,2= female,3 = other)).
```

What’s going wrong here? Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value can be quoted

```
library(dplyr)
bwdata6 <- bwdata6 %>% 
           mutate(across(c(Gender), ~recode(.x, '1' = 'male', 
                    '2' = 'female', 
                '3' = 'other')))
```

---

As a reproducible example

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 1)
recode(v1, '1'= male)
```

> Error in list2(...) : object 'male' not found

With quotes,

```
recode(v1, '1'= 'male', '2' = 'female', '3' = 'other')
#[1] "male"   "female" "other"  "male"
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I need to recode the within the dataset. Hence the code... bwdata6 <- bwdata6 %>% mutate(across(c(Gender), ~recode(.x, ‘1’ = male, ‘2’ = female, ‘3’ = other))) Why am I getting the 'object male not found error'?

Comment: @DrZaheer the first block of code in my post does that

Comment: @DrZaheer f you check my code and yours, the `male` , `female` or `other` are not quoted in your code while it is quoted in the solution I posted

Comment: ahh, I see now (my bad!). Let me give that a go and see what happens.